# I have an Asus R558U and I can't open CD ROM drive

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, optical-drive

I bought this new laptop and one day later I realized that the laptop has a CD-ROM drive but i can't open it - I mean there is no button on the side of the laptop to open it or anything - if I put a needle in the hole which is near the bottom it's not opening either, and if I go to `My Computer` there is a DVD-ROM or something where I can open it too, but I don't have these three ways.

Comment: If you right click the drive that you can see in Explorer you should see an "Eject" option. Does that do anything?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just a blanking plate?

Comment: Which model of r558u do you have? There are r558uv, r558uq, r558ur, r558uj, r558uf, r558ub and r558ua - https://www.asus.com/search/results.aspx?SearchKey=r558u

Answer (score -1):

I also had same problem, but after few minutes I saw there is no drive in it! It's just a place you can install the DVD drive if you want.

For reference, mine is Asus r558.